# Django filter using **kwargs

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to filter using some fields in an array like:

```
qs = Model.objects.all()
fields_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']

for field in fields_list:
    filter = {field: 20}
    qs.filter(**filter)

return qs
```

This piece of code, works in shell but not in runtime. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: The filter is not applied during runtime

Comment: you're not returning anything, so I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve at runtime (I don't see a function that returns `qs.filter(**filter)`). Note that `qs.filter()` doesn't change `qs`.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
filter = {}
for field in fields_list:
    filter.update({field: 20})
qs = qs.filter(**filter)
return qs
```

Comment: Okay, I never assign the filter result in a variable. Thank you!

Comment: Also there's a slight difference between adding the filters in the for-loop or outside of the for-loop. My function returns `qs.filter(a=20, b=20, c=20)` whereas yours returns (assuming to reassign to `qs`) `qs.filter(a=20).filter(b=20).filter(c=20)`. Same result if you're not spanning relationships, but different if `a`, `b` or `c` span relationships.